# Mutate across multiple columns using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I am trying to calculate rowwise averages for a number of columns. Could somebody please explain why the code below only calculates the mean for the two variables in the code (var_1 and var_13), rather than the mean for all 13 columns?

```
df %>% 
rowwise() %>%
  mutate(varmean = mean(var_1:var_13)) -> df
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(varmean = mean(c_across(mpg:vs)))
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 32 x 12
# Rowwise: 
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb varmean
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4    40.0
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4    40.1
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1    31.7
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1    52.8
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2    73.2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1    47.7
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4    81.2
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2    33.1
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2    36.7
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4    42.8
# ... with 22 more rows
```

and without `rowwise()` and using `base R`s `rowMeans()`:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(varmean = rowMeans(across(mpg:vs)))
```

returns

```r
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  varmean
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 39.99750
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 40.09938
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 31.69750
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 52.76687
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 73.16375
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 47.69250
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 81.24000
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 33.12250
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 36.69625
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 42.80750
```

Comment: Brilliant, c_across works well for that example! Thanks.

Can it be used in instances where you wish to apply across multiple columns but they are not all next to each other e.g., mpg:hp, wt:carb ?

Comment: Yes, just wrap it a `c`: `mean(c_across(c(mpg:hp, wt:carb)) `

Comment: There are also other selecting possibilities. Like unselecting a column or match it by name/string or simply by index.

Comment: Thanks again Martin, ridiculously obvious now you've pointed out! Thanks.